# MongoDB, java connector, one to one connections

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB Java Connector (4.7.0) to add documents to a new database - and I'm trying to get the links to occur between the **Person** and **Hobby** objects.

I've got the ObjectId going into the Collections, however when I look at the resulting data with queries (using DBSchema or any other ui) I don't see the connections, I see the two data tables, and the ObjectId in the relevant Person field under hobby, but no linking between the two.

Is there any way to do this without using POJO?
FWIW I don't want to use POJO as I don't want a structured document, one of the reasons I am trying to use MongoDB is for the ability to add/change data in the underlying 'json'.

```
mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri);
db = mongoClient.getDatabase("testing");

MongoCollection<Document> hobby = db.getCollection("hobby");
hobby.drop();
InsertOneResult gaming = hobby.insertOne(new Document("name", "gaming"));
InsertOneResult running = hobby.insertOne(new Document("name", "running"));

MongoCollection<Document> person = db.getCollection("person");
person.drop();
person.insertMany(
    Arrays.asList(
            new Document("name", "Max").append("age", 24).append("hobby_id", gaming.getInsertedId()),
            new Document("name", "Alex").append("age", 25).append("hobby_id", gaming.getInsertedId()),
            new Document("name", "Claire").append("age", 19).append("hobby_id", running.getInsertedId()))
);
```

Comment: The reason why i went this route is because of this article: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much scratching of head, this is what i've come up with that actually works:

```
Object getRef(InsertOneResult result) {
    MongoCollection<Document> hobby = db.getCollection("hobby");
    return hobby.find(eq("_id", result.getInsertedId())).first();
}

public MongoDbTesting(String uri) {

    mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri);
    db = mongoClient.getDatabase("testing_hobby");

    MongoCollection<Document> hobby = db.getCollection("hobby");
    hobby.drop();
    InsertOneResult gaming = hobby.insertOne(new Document("name", "gaming"));
    InsertOneResult running = hobby.insertOne(new Document("name", "running"));

    MongoCollection<Document> person = db.getCollection("person");
    person.drop();
    person.insertMany(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Document("name", "Max").append("age", 24).append("hobby", getRef(gaming)),
                    new Document("name", "Alex").append("age", 25).append("hobby", getRef(gaming)),
                    new Document("name", "Claire").append("age", 19).append("hobby", getRef(running)))
    );
}
```